# Palindrome using recursion

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7, python-requests

Please help me to code correctly in Python.

```
T = int(input("Number of test cases: "))    
for i in range(T+1):
    
    def checkPalindrome(str):
            l=len(str)
        
            if l==0 or l==1:
                return "It is a palindrome"
            
            if str[0]!=str[-1]:
                return "It is not a palindrome"
            
            else:
                str_new= str[1::-1]
            
                output= checkPalindrome(str_new)
                return output
            
            
            
            
str= [input(). split() for i in range(T) ]
checkPalindrome(str)
```

It is not working.

Comment: Edit the question to explain "it is not working". What exactly happens, what should happen?

Comment: You don't need to define the function `T` different times. You are also passing your entire *list* of test cases to `checkPalindrome` at once, rather than calling `checkPalindrome` on each test case separately.

Comment: You generally do not want to name variables `str` in Python.  `str` is a built-in function name for converting variables to `string` objects.

Answer (score 1):

The updated string for the next recursive call was not right. The format for slicing follows `[start:end:step]`. So `str[1::-1]` implied to start from index one and go back backward by 1 step (as denoted by -1). 
 The new string had to start from index one up to end excluding the last character. That can be done like this.

```
str_new = str[1:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```py
def checkPalindrome(word):
    l = len(word)
    if l == 0 or l == 1:
        return "It is a palindrome"        
    if word[0] != word[-1]:
        return "It is not a palindrome"
    return checkPalindrome(word[1:-1])
            
t = int(input("Number of test cases: "))

for i in range(t):
    print(checkPalindrome(input()))
```